# Does there exist a closed form for partial sums of $\sum_{i=1}^n(i\cdot b\mod k)$ for general $b$, $n$, $k$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic

Here's my attempt at solving this:

First, I noticed that $b = (b\mod k)+mk$ for some $m$. Then

$$(2b\mod k) + (b\mod k)=(3b\mod k)+pk$$
 for some other integer $p$. So then the partial sum up to $n$ equals the basic arithmetic sum $\sum_{i=1}^n b$ minus some multiple of $k$.

So next, I tried to figure out what that multiple of $k$ would be for a given partial sum up to $n$. From that, I discovered that (assuming $b<k$) the partial sum up to $n=1$ is off by $0$ multiples of $k$, and after that, the $n$th partial sum is off by the $(n-1)$th partial sum + $\left\lfloor \frac{n\cdot b}{k} \right\rfloor$.

From there, I can't find a clearly way to get a closed form, and any progress I make seems to only complicate it further. A lot of this I've discovered through programming, and for those it would help I have a [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/StrikingGrownService) with my code.

In that link, the array `diff` contains how many multiples of $k$ the $n$th partial sum is off by, the array `x` contains my attempt to find a closed form of `diff`, the array `y` contains the floor term for each $n$, and `length` is another array where I was trying to find a pattern in the floor terms.